# How do I configure DNS now that OS X Server doesn't support it?

Tags: mojave, dns, server.app

I was using OS X Server to run DNS for my local network.  As many know, the Mojave version of Server dropped a lot of the services that were there, one of which was DNS.  Unfortunately I didn't read the fine print when I upgraded my server to Mojave and was later surprised when I couldn't find the DNS settings in Server any longer.

The thing is that DNS is still running.  I can still hit my servers within my local network by name same as I was in High Sierra.  The problem is I have no way to make changes or even pull the settings so I can migrate to another DNS server.

Is there a way from the CLI to grab the settings from the old DNS server instance?  Then how do I shut that one down so I can try to migrate to another version?

Comment: I ran across this the other day, and while it does not answer all of your question specifically it does give you a GUI into the DNS server on macOS Mojave https://cutedgesystems.com/software/DNSEnablerForMojave/

Answer (score 2):

#### Locating configs with `lsof`

You could use `lsof` to try and find out what files the running DNS server is currently using and perhaps find out where the existing files are located.

```
$ lsof -p $(pgrep -f <name of DNS server>)
```

**NOTE:** I believe the configuration files are typically located here ,`/Library/Server/`, so you may want to look through there for them.

You may also want to look at the following resources regarding this from Apple:

#### BIND

*[DNS on Mojave server](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8612336)*

> DNS is no longer included in Server.app so you will have to do it
>   either on a Mac running an older version of macOS and hence older
>   version of Server.app or do it via the command line.
>
> If you manually install BIND then at least the config files will be
>   the same as previously used in Server.app although in a different
>   location

Based on this it sounds like you may be able to simply take your existing configs, if you can find them, and use them directly with BIND.

#### Service Migration Guide

Also take a look at this guide put out by Apple titled: [macOS Server
Service Migration Guide v1.2](https://developer.apple.com/support/macos-server/macOS-Server-Service-Migration-Guide.pdf).

#### References

- [Setting up a local DNS server on OSX](http://www.fullybaked.co.uk/articles/setting-up-a-local-dns-server-on-osx)
- [Configuring Your Own DNS Server on Mac OS X](http://www.natemcintyre.com/blog/2016/8/25/configuring-your-own-dns-server-on-mac-os-x)